# Magento 2.4 Error flushing Varnish server. Host: "127.0.0.1". PURGE response code: 501 message: Not Implemented

Tags: magento2.4, cache, upgrade, varnish, localhost

We are using Magento 2.4.5-p1 and PHP 8.1 versions.

When we are running upgrade commands getting an issue of -

```
Error flushing Varnish server. Host: "127.0.0.1". PURGE response code: 501 message: Not Implemented
```

Does Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to invalidate a Varnish cache using the `PURGE` request method on a system that doesn't support this request method.

At first sight it doesn't look like Varnish itself, because Varnish would return a `405 Method Now Allowed` status.

Go through the following steps to figure out what's going on:

1. Look at your Magento configuration for HTTP caching hosts
2. Check the host & port of the caching servers that are configured
3. Try to access the system that is referenced by the HTTP caching hosts (based on the error this is running locally)
4. Check if that system is indeed a Varnish service
5. If not, either properly install/Configure Varnish or remove the HTTP caching configuration in Magento
6. If so, dig up the VCL configuration (usually in `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`) and check if the `PURGE` request method is properly implemented

For more information about Varnish & Magento, have a look at the following tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem and have raised another question about it - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371227/varnish-cache-wont-clear-on-magento-2-4-2/371238?noredirect=1#comment509045_371238

When I use Flush Cache from the admin, Nginx log contains a 501 error for the Purge command.

As far as I understand it, it means PURGE isn't available to / on the website because it's in a Docker not as a standalone service.

I've spent days on this and still can't figure it out.

Any help would be most welcome.